# How can I setup an integration between Salesforce CRM and Microsoft SQL Server using PHPToolKit?

Tags: api, webservices, sqlserver

How can I setup an integration between Salesforce CRM and Microsoft SQL Server using PHPToolKit? We dont want to use any ETL toolkit to integrate this two environments. We would like to pull the SQL data according to the business logic requests.
Currently, we can see that only data can be pushed to salesforce using this Toolkit. Does anyone have an idea, how rather we can pull the data on request from salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

There are many samples in the official page.

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Samples

You should be able to query

```
 <?php
// SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR - folder that contains the PHP Toolkit and your WSDL
// $USERNAME - variable that contains your Salesforce.com username (must be in the form of an email)
// $PASSWORD - variable that contains your Salesforce.com password

define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "../../soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once ('../userAuth.php');
try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

  $query = 'SELECT Id,Name from Account limit 5';
  $response = $mySforceConnection->query(($query));

  foreach ($response->records as $record) {
    print_r($record);
    print_r("<br>");

**INSERT INTO MS SQL**
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to Query Sql records and insert in Salesforce

Comment: You have to... user the upsert methods.

Comment: Upsert means  Insert or Update. First define field as external id in the SF object (commonly, you should save  in this field the PK of the MS SQL table)

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Upsert_Sample_(Enterprise)